# Unclear how to prove this logarithmic reduction of a sequence, in reference to the birthday problem

Tags: logarithms, recreational-mathematics, birthday

On page 46 of Rouse Ball and HSM Coxeter's Mathematical Recreations and Essays, 13th ed., appears this step, in reference to [the birthday problem](https://math.info/Misc/Birthday_Problem/)
$$
(1-\frac{1}{365})(1-\frac{2}{365})...(1-\frac{n-1}{365})=1/2
$$
"by taking logarithms, we obtain approximately"
$$
\frac{1}{365}+\frac{2}{365}+...+\frac{n-1}{365}=log_e 2
$$

I'm unfamiliar with the step taken, and after some thinking and searching, haven't found any justification for the step.

Comment: This is what leads to $n \approx \tfrac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\tfrac{1}{4} + 2 \times \log_e(2) \times 365} \approx 23$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use the linear approximation
$$
\log(1-x) \approx -x
$$
which is good for $x$ close to $0$. And of course $\log(xy) = \log x + \log y$.

Comment: Oh cool, so then move the negative to the right and $-log(1/2)$ becomes $log(2)$. Pretty cool, thanks!

Comment: Yep, you got it